# A particle starts at the origin and travels along the positive $x$ axis. For the first one second, it's speed is $1m/s.$ Thereafter, its speed at

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

A particle starts at the origin and travels along the positive $x$ axis. For the first one second, it's speed is $1m/s.$  Thereafter, its speed at amy time $t$ is at most $9/10$ -ths of it's speed at time $t-1$  is:

$A.$ the particle reaches any point $x\gt 0$ at some finite time

$B.$ the particle must reach $x=10$

$C.$ the particle may or may not reach $x=9$ but it will never reach  $x=10$

$D.$ nothing of the above nature can be predicted without knowing the exact speed.

I tried, to approach this problem as follows:

> It is clear, from the given information,  that, at the first second, the particle moves $1m.$ Then, at the next second, if the particle, moves, a distance $d_2$ then, $d_2\leq \frac{9}{10}$. Similarly at the third second,  the particle, moves, a distance $d_3$ then, $d_3\leq \frac{9^2}{10^2}$. Continuing like this,  at the $kth$ second,  the particle, moves, a distance $d_k$ then, $d_k\leq \frac{9^k}{10^k}$. Now, $$s'_k=1+d_2+...+d_k\leq 1+\frac{9}{10} +\frac{9^2}{10^2}+...+\frac{9^k}{10^k}=s_k.$$ We note, that, $\{s_k\}$ converges to $10.$ So, $$1+d_1+d_2+...\leq 1+\frac{9}{10} +\frac{9^2}{10^2}+...+\frac{9^k}{10^k}+...=10.$$

But after this, I can't proceed any further. To be precise,  I am confused by the options given. I am not quite getting it...

Comment: Pretty sure it’s $C$. The particle can’t reach $10$ in finite time, and may or may not reach $9$ given the constraints of the problem

Comment: @Chris Thank you! But is it the only reasoning you used to assert $C$ as the answer? Your reasonings are reasonable though...

Comment: yup that’s it. You showed it can’t reach $10$ in finite time, and this answer is the only one that says that.

Comment: @Chris Thanks a lot! I do get it now... If you post this as an answer , I 'll be glad to accept it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s $C$, as you have shown the particle can’t reach $10$ in finite time. The only option which allows this is $C$, which also says pretty much nothing about $9$ as it’s a may or may or not statement, and we can clearly reach $9$ in finite time in som cases so it’s not impossible.